# SQLite with c# Metro app CRUD operation Syntax?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, microsoft-metro

I making a Windows 8 metro app. I am using SQLite for database purpose.
Somewhere I read that to insert into database use this command:

```
 db.Insert(new Person() { FirstName = "Tim", LastName = "Heuer" });
```

Now I need syntax for delete and update

I tried this but error is coming:

```
db.Delete(new Tasks() { Title = "dixit" });
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to add more detail.  What is your SQLite database schema (open SQLite with the database file, and type `.schema` from the SQLite console)?  What is the type of `db`, and how is it initialized?  What is the error you are seeing (preferably with stack trace)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
        var db = new SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection(DBPath);

        // Empty the Customer and Project tables 
        var customers = await db.Table<Customer>().ToListAsync();
        foreach (Customer customer in customers)
        {
            await db.DeleteAsync(customer);
        }
```